# Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php on line 611

Tags: magento-enterprise

I am using magento enterprise edition (Magento ver. 1.14.0.1) got this error of Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT when use web service call from mobile app. After some research i got that in package.php file need to check HTTP_USER_AGENT where it's having if condition

> if (!empty(self::$_regexMatchCache[$rule['regexp']][$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']]))

also found that in System > Configuration >Design we can add exception to change theme for mobile which in my case is blank, is this case i am getting this error or some thing else?